# Was the Father's will always subordinate to the Son's will?

Tags: jesus

Matthew 26:42-43 King James Version

> He went away again the second time, and prayed, saying, O my Father, if this cup may not pass away from me, except I drink it, thy will be done. And he came and found them asleep again: for their eyes were heavy.

The scene underscores Jesus' submission to the Father's will and his redemptive sacrifice. This event is central to Christian theology, representing Jesus' surrender into the hands of soldiers as part of the divine plan for humanity's redemption.

Matthew 26:53 King James Version

> Thinkest thou that I cannot now pray to my Father, and he shall presently give me more than twelve legions of angels?

This passage seems to suggest that, in stating that He could summon angels through prayer to the Father, Jesus was highlighting His authority over circumstances, including the Father's already established will. This prayer would represent a channel to express, if necessary, the adjustment of the Son's will in line with the already established redemptive plan, disregarding the Father's will.

Was the Father's will always subordinate to the Son's will?

Comment: I feel you actually wanted to ask: " Was the Son's will always subordinate to the Father's will "

Comment: This should probably be moved to Christianity.SE

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the mysteries of prayer - even as Christians, we are told to ask in the name of Jesus:

- John 14:12-14 - Truly, truly, I tell you, whoever believes in Me will also do the works that I am doing. He will do even greater things than these, because I am going to the Father. And I will do whatever you ask in My name, so that the Father may be glorified in the Son. **If you ask Me for anything in My name, I will do it**.
- John 15:16 - You did not chose Me, but I chose you and appointed you, that you should go and you should bear fruit, and your fruit should remain, so that **whatever you might ask the Father in My name, He may give you**.
- John 16:23, 24 - In that day you will no longer ask Me anything. Truly, truly, I tell you, **whatever you ask the Father in My name, He will give you**. Until now you have not asked for anything in My name. Ask and you will receive, so that your joy may be complete.

Thus, according to Jesus, "*whatever you ask the Father in My name, He will give you*".  This does NOT mean that the Father's will is subordinate to our will!!  It is simply saying that when we ask in the name of Jesus, we are asking according to the will of Jesus.  This confirms what Jesus said in John 10:30 -

> I and the Father are one.

Since there is such unity between the Father and Jesus, Jesus asks in accordance with, and submits to the Father's will.  The same should be true of Christians as well.

This is further reinforced by the intercessor, the Holy Spirit" who "intercedes for the saints according to the will of God" (Rom 8:27).  That is, Christians "live in the spirit according to the will of God" (1 Peter 4:6).

Such a Christian life is contradistinction to the unsaved who live "according to the will of The Ruler of The Authority of The Air" (ie, Satan).